# how to stop tensorboard in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I wanted to stop current tensorboard notebook running in google colab because I could not start another tensorboard server. I searched but everyone is showing how to start a tensorboard in google colab, did not find how to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around.
First find the process ID of tensorboard by running this in colab

```
from tensorboard import notebook
notebook.list()
```

it will show this output and highlighted one (pid) is process id
[colab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi2Qi.png)

Next run this command to kill the process

```
!kill -9 2712
```